# Zoom In and Out Based on the Range

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, zooming

Once user click a zoom in button, the program able to find median the range of the data and zoom according based on zoom Level.

Example

```
    var list=[0,1,2,3,4,5, ...., 100]
    var zoom=2; // Max 5
```

If Zoom Level is 2, its will zoom in between 20 to 80.  Zoom again, its will zoom in between 40 to 60. Zoom out, its will be 40 to 60.

May i know how to use math and algorithm to perform this code?

Comment: do you have some more cases with values?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add both more information about the desired behavior, and also the code of your attempt at it so far.

Answer (score 0):

"Zooming" array seems strange but I guess you are looking for something like this :

```js
let list = [];
let zoom = 2;

for(let i=1; i<=100; i++) {
  list[i]=i;
}

function getZoomedList(zoom, list, minZoom, maxZoom) {
  startI = list.length/(maxZoom*2) * zoom;
  endI = list.length - startI + 1;
  return list.slice(startI, endI);
}

console.log(getZoomedList(2, list, 0, 5));
```